# Проблема с синхронизацией gradle

Tags: android-gradle

я начинающий андроид программист и хочу сделать программу с использованием firebase, до этого один раз подключал смотря видео урок от Гоша Дударь но так и не закончил, прошла неделя я снова начала, делаю точно также как на видео и выходит ошибка

> Task :app:createMockableJar UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild SKIPPED
>   Task :app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
>
> Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED
>   C:\Users\nurs9.DESKTOP-E8U1VB4\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication3\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
>       uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:19.0.0] C:\Users\nurs9.DESKTOP-E8U1VB4.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\333a4b14f4a36b22a5b8879ae448e614\firebase-iid-19.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 15
>       Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,
>           or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
>           or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.iid" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

  > Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:19.0.0] C:\Users\nurs9.DESKTOP-E8U1VB4.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\333a4b14f4a36b22a5b8879ae448e614\firebase-iid-19.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 15
  >   Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,
  >       or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
  >       or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.iid" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
4 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 3 up-to-date
ERROR: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:19.0.0] C:\Users\nurs9.DESKTOP-E8U1VB4.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\333a4b14f4a36b22a5b8879ae448e614\firebase-iid-19.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 15
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.iid" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно установить минимальную версию SDK - 16, т.к. firebase-iid:19.0.0 использует ее.

Устанавливается в build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 16
}
```

Comment: я значит должен в build.gradle добавить этот методdefaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 16
}

Comment: не добавить,а изменить. Он уже там присутствует